# Closing questions with useless reasons

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

A moderator is closing those questions which are worth discussion and help, and the reason that Mr ChrisF is giving is "This question does not meet enough of our six guidelines for constructive subjective questions."

An advise for Mr ChrisF: Go through your business plan again and understand that you should give those guidelines to the members before they open any question here. This is a complete waste of time if you jump right between the discussion quoting guideline issues.

It is a complete waste of time.

Comment: (a) Which questions are you speaking of? (b) Aren't some of said guidelines already part of the FAQ?

Comment: Could you link to an example of what you're talking about? (There are many users named Chris on the site.) When you're ask a question, it has a big box at the side asking you to read the FAQ before posting.

Comment: [This](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/100477/need-help-while-creating-base-of-my-website) is the question he's referring to and the Chris mentioned is [ChrisF](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/47/chrisf) a mod on Prog.SE

Comment: That's not even close to being a real question. If it will make you feel better, I'll ask ChrisF to change the close reason to **Not a Real Question:** *It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.*

Comment: To find out how to ask questions on Programmers.SE that will not get closed, read http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq. All of the guidelines are available there.  It might be worth a little bit of your time to get to know us; we work a little differently than all of those other forums out there.

Comment: If it's worth a discussion, it's not fit for the site. That is where you're looking for chat.

Comment: I suppose someone should mention that mistakes made in the flush of excitement when you find the site won't be held against you. *Please* take a few breaths and come back to our community; browse a little to learn how thing work and what is or is not well received, then try again.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that most moderator aren't working for StackExchange (ChrisF isn't working for StackExchange and I doubt he cares much about StackExchange business model). And it's also worth mentioning that it's not because YOU think your question is good, that the EVERYONE thinks it's good.

Answer (score 17):

The guidelines are available in multiple places.

For instance, there is a handy link there on the right when you ask a question.

It says "How to ask" and has a nice summary and link to the FAQ:

[image]

Ignorance of the rules is not really an excuse, since the site has a multitude of "in your face" ways to show the information.

**That you chose to ignore the rules is not a problem with the site.**

Comment: And in the case the user didn't understand the questions he should ask on a SE site, users can still votes for closing a question, which is a way of saying, "You are asking the question in the wrong place."